# Sort Posts with custom meta key by default which is currently set as optional

Tags: wp-query, sort, array, meta-query

I'm new to Wordpress so please bear with me.

Please check [this link](http://minimalistarray.com/wptest/)

The posts are currently sorted by date. But if you mouse over on `Latest Articles` you see there are other options for sorting like `Most Viewed` `Most Liked` etc.

What I'm trying to do is make `Most Liked` the default sorting value instead of `Latest Articles`

I believe this could be done by modifying codes where the `wp_query args` are setup

The php file which controls the panel has this code -

`$args = array('posts_per_page' => $postsperpage);`

I've tried modifying it with this -

`$args = array('posts_per_page' => $postsperpage, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => IT_META_TOTAL_LIKES);`

But it doesn't solve the purpose!

Can anyone tell me how do I do this?

Comment: Add single quotes around 'IT_META_TOTAL_LIKES'.  Assuming that is your meta_key.

Comment: @josh That's the meta_key, but adding single quotes doesn't make it work! :(

Comment: did you tried meta_value, only instead of meta_value_num, these are some hacks that works most of the time, also u'll be needing the single quotes around your meta_key name.

also you can use
$posts_results = new WP_Query($args);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($posts_results);echo "</pre>";, to check the query

Comment: @dot1 tried with meta_value..didn't work.
where do I add the `$posts_results` line?

Comment: You are querying the posts on your page, using new WP_Query, just store it in a variable and then echo "<pre>"; print_r($variable_name);echo "</pre>"; to check the query and results

Comment: did that still no luck!

Comment: that was not to make it work, it is for debugging purpose, check the query it generates, try it in your PhpMyAdmin or something

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11409/discussion-between-sam-dg-and-dot1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the change you require is a modification to your theme, it will take time and you might end up corrupting it if you are not comfortable working with WordPress, instead of that you can make a child theme for it and make whatever change you want inside it.

A replacement and partial solution would be to add a js in your theme, to click on the link as soon as the div is there, it will refresh the posts automatically for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 if( jQuery('.home.blog').find('.articles .icon-liked.liked ') != ''){
   jQuery('.home.blog').find('.articles .icon-liked.liked ').click();
   jQuery('.home.blog').find('.articles .sortbar-title').html('MOST LIKED');
 }
});
```

Also I did modified your theme.php to include script in page, added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THEME_JS_URI; ?>/custom.js"></script>
```

to function

```
 it_footer_scripts()
```

its merely a solution but its a solution as of now.

Comment: I think this has messed up the sorting by date option.
`Latest Articles` & `Most Liked` now gives the same view!
Also, new posts do not show up in that panel.

Comment: for that to be fixed there are lots of changes required...maybe I can fix that later

Comment: this should be good till a better solution is found :)